# how to get selected dates in react calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I downloaded react-native-material-calandarview inside my project.

They just give some piece of code to get calendar. https://github.com/NuclleaR/react-native-material-calendarview.

I just selected `datesSelection={'range'}`, but I dont know where I get the selected dates. If `datesSelection={'single'}` it return date in

```
onDateChange={data => {
    console.log(data.date);//date selected
}}
```

More code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Calendar
        width={(Dimensions.get('window').width)-32}
        height={280}
        tileHeight={35}
        style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
        topbarVisible={true}
        datesSelection={'range'}
        firstDayOfWeek="monday"
        showOtherDates="none"
        currentDate={this.state.today}
        selectedDates={this.state.dates}
        eventsDates={[]}
        eventsColor="#9C27B0"
        onDateChange={data => {
          //alert(sel_date);
            console.log(this.state.data);

        }}
        onMonthChange={month => {
          //alert(month)
            console.log(month);

        }}
      />
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the onChange will show you the date the user selects it's up to you to make a function to store these in redux/local state. Same for a range the onChange will return you that range in the argument you're passing to it

So what you can do is

In HTML:

`onDateChange={this.onChange}`

Component method:

`onChange = (date) => { this.setState({ selectedDate: date }) };`

Comment: Have u tried this?? I cant able to make it work??.
When i changed to 'range', onDateChange called only when i selected first date, not firing at second selection